# Is there a way to get hot water without altering plumbing or electrical wiring too much?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water, heat

Is there a way (other than collecting water and heating it on the stove ) to get hot/warm water from the tap without having to alter existing plumbing or electrical wiring ?

Perhaps use a chemical reaction to provide the heat to warm the water ?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. This question does not appear to be about chemistry, as defined in our [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It is likely to be put on hold for that reason. If your intent was to use a chemical reaction to provide the heat to warm the water, we need to know that in the question and it would be on topic. Otherwise, perhaps this question belongs at [Home Improvement?](http://diy.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @BenNorris I edited the question to include the verbiage you used in your comment. Hope it is sufficiently on topic now.

Answer (score 2):

Crystallization of a supersaturated solution of sodium acetate will release heat - **once**. But then it is just a solid. It works nicely for pocket warmers, but since you have to heat the flexible container in boiling water prior to re-use, this and other comparable processes are of little use for a water supply.

At the end of the day, you won't get around plumbing to tap an energy source.

Your options would be:

- solarthermal
- geothermal
- heat released from the fermentation of organic waste

Comment: Yes I did think of hand warmers but the idea of pre-boiling it was not appealing. Have you heard of coffee joulies? (joulies.com?) These things lower/maintain temperature. Wonder if a similar thing exists for increasing the temperature of water/fluids.

Comment: You can always dissipate the heat and loose it to the environment, but harvesting energy against a temperature gradient does not work. Putting your feet in a cold creek to warm them up while the water cools down is not an option. Thermodynamics is a harsh mistress ;)